# How to get epochs from eeg data in python?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, python, eeg, feature-extraction

I am working on sleep stage classification and have EEG data from the link : https://physionet.org/content/hmc-sleep-staging/1.1/

I am using pyedflib to extract the data.

I am tring to extract the epoches by slicing the data in 30 seconds.But the issue is no of annotations and no of ecpochs extracted are not matching.

Can anyone help me with epoch extraction.

Code :

```
import pyedflib
import pandas as pd
signals,signal_headers, header = highlevel.read_edf(files1)
df=pd.DataFrame(signals.T,columns=sig_header)
eeg_fm1=df['EEG F4-M1']
epochs=eeg_fm1[0:len(eeg_fm1):30]
```

Comment: Could you provide a plot of the data? Do you want to know the signal processing needed to extract the epochs or how to use existing code that does that? If it is the latter, that is likely off topic for this site. (see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes I want to know the signal processing to extract the 30 sec epochs from the signals. The given code is just for reference for the library i am using.